# Need help with linear transformations!

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let Mn,n denote the vector space of n x n matrices and let T: Mn,n → Mn,n be the linear transformation that is given by T(A) = A + A^T.

1. Prove that the image of T is the set of all matrices for which B = B^T
2. Describe the kernel and find a spanning set for it

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1. You need to show that

- $T(A)$ is symmetric for any matrix $A$, and
- any symmetric matrix $B$ can be written as $B=T(A)$ for some matrix $A$.

---

2. Write down (in terms of $A$) what $T(A)=0$ implies about $A$. There is a [name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix) for this kind of matrix. What degrees of freedom do you have in defining such a matrix? (What must the diagonal entries be? If I know the $(1,2)$ entry is $4$, what does that tell me about other entries of the matrix?)